# Base class Task<> has no empty constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance, task

I have a C# code

```
private class EvaluationTask : Task<Solution> {
    private Problem problem_;
    private Solution solution_;
    public EvaluationTask(Problem problem, Solution solution)
    {
        problem_ = problem;
        solution_ = solution;
    }
}
```

Now, I am getting error `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<>` does not contain constructor that takes 0 arguments. From previous answers posted, I found that one has to define empty constructor in the base class. But since my base class is `Task<>`, how do I add an empty constructor to it?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit: I have to inherit task<> because I have to use the method EvaluationTask in a code:

```
taskList_ = new List<Task<Solution>>();
taskList_.Add(new MultithreadedEvaluator.EvaluationTask (problem_, solution));
```

I don't know about task composition, so if it is necessary can anyone help with that? Or if by any way I can avoid inheriting Task and still implement taskList_.Add()?

Comment: There should be no reason at all for you to inherit `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<>`. Have you tried composition, have you taken a look at the `IAwaitable<>` interface? Does your implementation adhere to the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Answer (score 2):

When you inherit from a class, in your constructors you need to call any of the constructors of the base class. In your case, since you aren't calling any constructor, the compiler try to call a parameterless constructor of the base class, but `Task<>` haven't a parameterless constructor.

As you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9265327/5178207), inheriting from `Task<>` probably isn't a good idea, but you can do something like this:

```
class EvaluationTask : Task<Evaluation>
{
    public EvaluationTask() 
        : base(DoWork) { }

    private static Evaluation DoWork()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a perfectly good and correct answer, but unfortunately the `DoWork` function has to be `static` and thus has no obvious way of accessing any instance members that likely need to exist as the very point of overriding `Task<TResult>` in the first place. In another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489462/147511) on this page, I provide a workaround for this problem, in case you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

When using `Task<T>`, you must supply the `Func<>` or `Action<>` delegate (i.e., function pointer to the desired work to perform) *as a constructor argument*. It is indeed somewhat unfortunate that there isn't any constructor which lets you bypass this requirement and supply the delegate at a later time (yet obviously still prior to calling `Start()`), since this **severely hampers** the ability to extend the `Task` and `Task<TResult>` classes via inheritance altogether.

The reason it's a crippling omission is that no delegate you supply as a constructor argument can possibly directly incorporate a reference to the instance you are trying to construct, since that instance (again, obviously) doesn't exist yet, chicken/egg style.

Hence @Arturo's answer, which shows that you can, in fact, supply a ***static*** delegate, but since such a delegate has no obvious way of referencing one particular `Task` instance, it essentially defeats the purpose of inheriting from `Task` in the first place.

> <sub>--- ***reflection disclaimer*** ---
> I've been using this technique in my own projects for years on **.NET Framework 4.7** (desktop) with no problems whatsoever, but please note that code which uses reflection to access non-public behavior is subject to breakage if the .NET internals change in a later version. You have been warned.</sub>

Here's a more flexible workaround for the problem, a general-purpose **abstract base class for `Task<TResult>`** which allows you to provide the desired work code in the normal way for derived type hierarchies: as an instance method override. This is a reflection solution; the way it works is to provide a dummy "placeholder" delegate to the **base constructor call**, but then immediately in the **constructor body**, swap it out for the "real," desired abstract instance work method, which at that point is no longer unknowable or rather *unbindable*.

```
abstract class TaskBase<TResult> : Task<TResult>
{
    readonly static FieldInfo m_action =
       typeof(Task).GetField("m_action", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    readonly static Func<TResult> _dummy = () => default;

    public TaskBase(CancellationToken ct, TaskCreationOptions opts)
        : base(_dummy, ct, opts) =>
            m_action.SetValue(this, (Func<TResult>)function);

    public TaskBase(CancellationToken ct)
        : this(ct, TaskCreationOptions.None)
    { }

    public TaskBase(TaskCreationOptions opts)
        : this(default, opts)
    { }

    public TaskBase()
        : this(default, TaskCreationOptions.None)
    { }

    protected abstract TResult function();  // <-- override with your work code
};
```

To use this, simply inherit from `TaskBase<TResult>`, and override the abstract method `function()` to implement your task work logic. There is no need for a version of this base class where the work function accepts a `AsyncState` argument/parameter(s), since you can simply declare all the relevant context for the specific work instance as additional instance fields (and instance methods, and instance properties...) in your derived class. So the constructor variations I declared exactly match those provided by `Task<TResult>`, but minus the 'function' and 'state' arguments. And finally, don't forget to call `Start()` when your packaged work instance is ready to go!

---

The above is a actually a simplified version of the `TaskBase<TResult>` code I've had much success with. My enhanced version avoids creating the `Func<TResult>` delegate which must be created for each `TaskBase` instance in order to "wrap" the C# method `function()` as an instance delegate. Instead of initially providing a 'dummy' delegate to the base constructor, I always provide (the same) static delegate, a singleton which acts as a "thunk" that universally reinterprets, or "upcasts" a `Task<TResult>`'s `AsyncState` object as a pertinent `TaskBase<TResult>` instance, and then calls `function()` directly on that instance. Like so:

```
static Func<Object,TResult> thunk = obj => ((TaskBase<TResult>)obj).function();
```

So `fn_redirect` is the only "excess" delegate we need to create once at startup, and this singleton is always passed-in as the base constructor work delegate. Now as with that constructor argument, the "async state" object is also only passed in as a constructor argument and normally cannot later be changed. We don't need a "dummy" in this approach, because you can--and should--pass in 'null' for `state`. Similar to before we use reflection to set a field, but this time it's `m_stateObject` field instead of `m_action`, to replace the 'null' value we just installed for the instance `this` pointer:

```
public TaskBase(CancellationToken ct, TaskCreationOptions opts)
    : base(thunk, default(Object), ct, opts)
{
    m_stateObject.SetValue(this, this);
}
```

Voila, allocating one extra delegate for each `TaskBase` instance is avoided. Finally, recall that there are no adverse loss of capability when co-opting the state object for the purpose of this enhancement because as I mentioned earlier, the whole `AsyncObject` argument-passing mechanism is unnecessary when you entirely control the derived class you are writing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an inheritable class that inherits from `Task<T>`, and allows delayed assignment of the task's function. The constructor takes no arguments. The function is assigned by the property `Function`.

```
public class FlexibleTask<T> : Task<T>
{
    private readonly Helper _helper;

    public Func<T> Function { set { _helper.SetFunction(value); } }

    public FlexibleTask() : base(GetFunction())
    {
        this._helper = TempHelper;
        TempHelper = null;
    }

    private static Func<T> GetFunction()
    {
        Func<T> function = Default;
        var helper = new Helper();
        helper.SetFunction = f => function = f;
        TempHelper = helper;
        return () => function();
    }

    private static readonly Func<T> Default = () =>
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Function is not set.");

    [ThreadStatic] private static Helper TempHelper;

    private class Helper
    {
        public Action<Func<T>> SetFunction {get; set;}
    }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
public class EvaluationTask : FlexibleTask<int>
{
}

var task = new EvaluationTask();
task.Function = () => 13;
task.Start();
var result = await task;
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
```

Output:

> Result: 13