# How can I create a class that is both a Task<T> and an IObservable<T>?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, rx.net

Recently I encountered a situation where having an asynchronous operation represented both as a `Task<T>` and as an `IObservable<T>` would be advantageous. The task representation maintains the state of the operation (`IsCompleted`, `IsFaulted` etc), while the observable representation enables the composition of multiple operations in interesting ways (`Concat`, `Merge`, `Switch` etc), handling automatically the cancellation of any operation that has been unsubscribed along the way, solving this way the problem of fire-and-forgotten asynchronous operations. So I've become interested about ways to combine these two representations.

The easy, and probably correct, way to combine them would be through composition: creating a type that stores internally a `Task<T>` and an `IObservable<T>`, and exposes them as two of its properties. But in this question I am interested about the challenging, and probably impractical, possibility of a type that **is** a `Task<T>` and **is** an `IObservable<T>` at the same time. A type that can be passed directly to APIs that accept either tasks or observables, and do the right thing in either case. So it can't be just a task-like object. It must inherit from the real thing, the `Task<T>` class itself. Something like this:

```
public class AsyncOperation<TResult> : Task<TResult>, IObservable<TResult>
{
    public AsyncOperation(Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> action)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Creating an `AsyncOperation` instance should invoke immediately the supplied action. In other words an `AsyncOperation` should represent a **hot** task/observable combo.

Is it possible to create such a type?

Btw here is a thread in the [ReactiveX/RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) library that proves that others have thought about this problem before: [No "isCompleted" or "isErrored" methods on Observable](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/1313)

Comment: Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts. Extending from `Task<T>` doesn't look problematic (it's not `sealed`), but maybe you can write what the problem is (preferable with a MCVE).

Comment: @Progman the problem is that all public `Task<T>` constructors create delegate tasks, while an asynchronous method creates a promise-style task. The constructors associated with promise-style tasks are private or internal.

Comment: Let me (quote][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh242974(v=vs.103] RX documentation.You do not need to implement the IObservable<T>/IObserver<T> interfaces yourself. Rx provides internal implementations of these interfaces for you and exposes them through various extension methods provided by the Observable and Observer types.

Comment: @FilipCordas sure. My problem is that the built-in implementations of the `IObservable<T>` interface, for example the return value of the `Observable.StartAsync` method, do not inherit from the `Task<T>` class. So I can't use the functionality of a task for an observable that represents a single asynchronous operation. And this functionality is needed in some scenarios. For example the execution flow may depend on whether the operation has completed successfully or not.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Again I don't see this being needed in any situation. I have never heard of an actual need to inherit from a Task<T> either, I was surprised it wasn't sealed. You can create a task from an observable and you can create an observable from a task.so the seams to be a nonexistent problem.

Comment: @FilipCordas yeap, you can certainly create an observable and a task that both represent the same asynchronous operation, and then have to carry both of them around in order to use whatever representation you need each time. This is what I did in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64659387/create-observable-from-periodic-async-request "Create observable from periodic async request") question, and I'm not particularly happy with the looks of it.

Comment: @FilipCordas FYI the `Observable.StartAsync` operator calls internally the `Task.ToObservable` extension method, that returns a wrapped instance of an internal [`SlowTaskObservable`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/7d369561aca0a161d68d8ef9b0658b8c6f5b3ed3/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Threading/Tasks/TaskObservableExtensions.cs#L19) class. This class stores the underlying task created when the `Observable.StartAsync` was invoked, but there is no way to get my hands on this task (except by using reflection tricks). My problem would be nonexistent **if** this task was accessible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to create an observable that inherits from `Task`, by using a genius technique described by @GlennSlayden in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265327/is-it-ok-to-derive-from-tpl-task-to-return-more-details-from-method/35420974#35420974) answer.

```
public class AsyncOperation<TResult> : Task<TResult>, IObservable<TResult>
{
    private readonly IObservable<TResult> _observable;
    private readonly Task<TResult> _promise;

    private AsyncOperation(Func<TResult> function) : base(() => function())
        => function = this.GetResult;

    private TResult GetResult() => _promise.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    public AsyncOperation(Func<CancellationToken, Task<TResult>> action)
        : this((Func<TResult>)null)
    {
        _observable = Observable.StartAsync(action, Scheduler.Immediate);
        _promise = _observable.ToTask();
        _promise.ContinueWith(_ => base.RunSynchronously(), default,
            TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    IDisposable IObservable<TResult>.Subscribe(IObserver<TResult> observer)
        => _observable.Subscribe(observer);
}
```

The above solution is not perfect because an instance of the derived class can never transition to the [`Canceled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus) state. This is a problem I don't know how to fix, and it may not be fixable, but it's probably not very important. A cancellation emerges as a `TaskCanceledException`, and handling this exception is the normal way of dealing with canceled tasks anyway.

Interestingly the asynchronous operation can be canceled by creating a dummy subscription and disposing it:

```
var operation = new AsyncOperation<TResult>(async cancellationToken => { /* ... */ });

operation.Subscribe(_ => { }, _ => { }).Dispose(); // Cancels the cancellationToken
```

I experimented with this class a bit and I found that it's less practical than I initially thought it would be. The problem is that many APIs exist that support both tasks and observables, and are identical otherwise (for example `Concat`, `Merge`, `Switch`, `Wait` etc). This leads to the frequent appearance of compile-time errors ([CS0121](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0121) ambiguous call). Resolving the ambiguities is possible by casting the type as either task or observable, but this is awkward, and negates the whole purpose of combining the two types in the first place.

---

**Clarification:** The line `_promise.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` may indicate at first glance that this implementation blocks a `ThreadPool` thread. This is not the case because the base `Task` is initially cold, and it's only warmed when the `_promise` has completed.