# How to pass additional context information along with tasks to Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

Consider the following ideal code (which doesn't work). I'm essentially trying to create a list of `Task`s that return a specific object, associate them with a `string` identifier, then execute all of them in bulk with `Task.WhenAll`. At the end of the execution, I need to have the **results** of those `Task`s still associated with the string identifiers they were originally created with:

```
public async Task<SomeObject> DoSomethingAsync(string thing)
{
    // implementation elided
}

public async Task<SomeObject> DoSomethingElseAsync(string thing)
{
    // different implementation elided
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<(string, SomeObject)>>
    DoManyThingsAsync(IEnumerable<string> someListOfStrings, bool condition)
{
    var tasks = new List<(string, Task<SomeObject>)>();

    foreach (var item in someListOfStrings)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            tasks.Add((item, DoSomethingAsync(item)));
        }
        else
        {
            tasks.Add((item, DoSomethingElseAsync(item)));
        }
    }

    // this doesn't compile, i'm just demonstrating what i want to achieve
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results;
}
```

This can be rewritten to the following:

```
public async Task<(string, SomeObject)> DoSomethingWrapperAsync(string thing)
    => (thing, await DoSomethingAsync(thing));

public async Task<(string, SomeObject)> DoSomethingElseWrapperAsync(string thing)
    => (thing, await DoSomethingElseAsync(thing));

public async Task<IEnumerable<(string, SomeObject)>>
    DoManyThingsAsync(IEnumerable<string> someListOfStrings, bool condition)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<(string, SomeObject)>>();

    foreach (var thing in someListOfStrings)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            tasks.Add(DoSomethingWrapperAsync(thing));
        }
        else
        {
            tasks.Add(DoSomethingElseWrapperAsync(thing));
        }
    }

    // this does compile
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return results;
}
```

The problem is that I need an extra wrapper method for every possible discrete async function I'm going to call, which feels unnecessary and wasteful and is a lot of code (because there will be MANY of these methods). Is there a simpler way of achieving what I need?

I looked into implementing the awaitable/awaiter pattern, but can't see how I could get it to work with `Task.WhenAll` which requires a collection of `Task` or `Task<TResult>`, since [the guidance seems to be "don't extend those classes"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265496/70345).

Comment: `await Tasks.WhenAll(tasks.Select(x => x.task))`?

Comment: Why do you need the tuples?

Comment: FYI you don't need a wrapper for each method. You could do: `public async Task<(string, T)> WrapperAsync<T>(string thing, Func<string, Task<T>> asyncFunc) => (thing, await asyncFunc(thing));` Then `tasks.Add(WrapperAsync(thing, DoSomethingAsync));`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Technically I don't, I just need a way to associate the relevant string with the result of the relevant method. (Assume that I cannot modify `SomeObject`'s definition to simply include this.) I suppose I could make a wrapper class, but that's much the same as the tuple IMO.

Comment: Also - I've been banging my head against this for a couple of hours so it's *very* likely I've missed something obvious - so please forgive me if this seems like a stupid question!

Comment: Why not keep the 'thing' in an entirely separate list?

Comment: The first item in each tuple isn't used in the code you posted, so I'm not sure what the association is achieving? If it is necessary, then you could do: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(x => x.Item2));`.

Comment: Sorry all - I elided a bit too much information - question has been updated with what I'm actually looking to return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either do the zipping as you go:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<(string, SomeObject)>>
    DoManyThingsAsync(IEnumerable<string> someListOfStrings, bool condition)
{
  var tasks = someListOfStrings
      .Select(async item =>
          condition ?
          (item, await DoSomethingAsync(item)) :
          (item, await DoSomethingElseAsync(item)))
      .ToList();
  return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Or, you can keep the input as a separate collection and zip it later:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<(string, SomeObject)>>
    DoManyThingsAsync(IEnumerable<string> someListOfStrings, bool condition)
{
  // Reify input so we don't enumerate twice.
  var input = someListOfStrings.ToList();

  var tasks = input
      .Select(item =>
          condition ?
          DoSomethingAsync(item) :
          DoSomethingElseAsync(item))
      .ToList();
  var taskResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

  return input.Zip(taskResults, (item, taskResult) => ((item, taskResult)));
}
```

Comment: I like the first approach. The second not so much, because it feels more error prone, and also because it elides async and await.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you are using `condition` to determine which method (of the exact same signature) is being called. Why not pass a callback that is called for each item instead of doing the logic inside the `foreach` loop?

```cs
public async Task<SomeObject> DoSomethingAsync(string thing)
{
    // ...
}

public async Task<SomeObject> DoSomethingElseAsync(string thing)
{
    // ...
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<(string, SomeObject)>> DoManyThingsAsync(IEnumerable<string> someListOfStrings, bool condition)
{
    Func<string, Task<SomeObject>> callback = condition ? DoSomethingAsync : DoSomethingElseAsync;

    var results = await Task.WhenAll(
        someListOfStrings.Select(async thing => (thing, await callback(thing)))
    );
    return results;
}
```

Furthermore, you can extract this as an extension method.

```cs
public static class AsyncExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<(T, TResult)>> WhenAllAsync(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, Task<TResult>> selector)
    {
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(
            collection.Select(async item => (item, await selector(item)))
        );
        return results;
    }
}

public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    // ...

    var results = await myListOfStrings.WhenAllAsync(condition ? DoSomethingAsync : DoSomethingElseAsync);

    // ...
}
```

Or do the mapping in the callback.

```cs
public static class AsyncExtensions
{
    public static Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> WhenAllAsync(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, Task<TResult>> selector)
        => Task.WhenAll(collection.Select(selector)));
}

public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    // ...

    var results = await myListOfStrings.WhenAllAsync(async thing => (thing, await (condition ? DoSomethingAsync(thing) : DoSomethingElseAsync(thing))));

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Combining `await` and `ContinueWith` is not a good idea. You are using two mechanisms that have slightly different semantics in order to accomplish the same thing. The `ContinueWith` is a [primitive](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html) method, and it should be avoided in general.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias fair point, I've updated my answer.

Comment: OK, I revoked my downvote. But honestly I am not inclined to upvote, because the `Process`/`ProcessAsync` method looks overly abstract to me. It is unlikely that this method will be used twice in the same project, and its name communicates poorly what this method is doing.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I wouldn't know if a method like that will be used twice or not, I don't know the project. As to being overly abstract, well, it's an easy way towards an extension method that may be used multiple times if that's the case.

Comment: `WhenAllAsync` is a better name than `ProcessAsync`. You could compare your extension method with the new API [`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0), that is going to be introduced in .NET 6.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias yeah, the main challenge I see in the question is actually determining the callback that does the processing and then using that to map both input and output together. Once you have the callback you can go a number of ways to do that mapping which may or may not require an extension method in the first place.

Comment: My main concern is that an extension method like the `WhenAllAsync` could be implemented in all sorts of ways, and have all sorts of signatures, and all these implementations and signatures would be valid in some context, and would fulfill a useful role. Regarding the implementation: should the tasks be generated and awaited one by one, or all together, or with some specific level of concurrency? Regarding the signature: should it return a `Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>` or a `Task<(TSource, TResult)[]>` or an `IAsyncEnumerable<(TSource, TResult, Exception)>`? So many options...